# Ubuntu 20.04 Going Non-Responsive

Tags: hardware, crash, reboot

**Environment:** HP Elite 8200, 20GB RAM, i7-2600 processor) running Ubuntu 20.04 as a home server (Samba, Docker, httpd, ssh) connected via Ethernet to my home network.

**Problem:** Every few days the machine is non-responsive. Pings return that the host is down, SSH fails to connect, even connecting mouse/keyboard/monitor to the machine gives an empty black screen. Upon hard reboot, it's like nothing ever happened for a few days.

**What I've tried**: Googling these symptoms doesn't return much. I've checked every setting I could find in Ubuntu's power management settings in case this was some suspended state but came up with nothing. As far as I can tell the logs don't show anything, but I'm a novice.

**syslog**

May 31 00:00:20 esvee systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

May 31 00:00:20 esvee systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

May 31 00:00:20 esvee systemd[1]: Failed to start Rotate log files.

May 31 00:08:01 esvee CRON[109755]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)

May 31 00:09:01 esvee CRON[109762]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)

May 31 00:09:04 esvee systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...

May 31 00:09:04 esvee systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.

May 31 00:09:04 esvee systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.

May 31 00:17:01 esvee CRON[109972]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

***I hard rebooted here***

May 31 03:57:10 esvee systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.

May 31 03:57:10 esvee systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.

May 31 03:57:10 esvee systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...

May 31 03:57:10 esvee systemd[1]: Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2f, date = 2019-02-17

May 31 03:57:10 esvee mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-33-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #37-Ubuntu
 SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-33.37-generic 5.4.34)

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=2fcd232a-16d1-4aa3-8788-430c7d5eeb07 ro quiet
 splash vt.handoff=7

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:

May 31 03:57:10 esvee systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine

May 31 03:57:10 esvee kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls

May 31 03:57:10 esvee mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1"

kern.log's last entry is several hours before:
May 30 18:22:24 esvee kernel: [89679.301450] audit: type=1400 audit(1590877344.766:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/expressvpn/resolv.conf" pid=1162 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=127 ouid=0

What am I missing? Is this a hardware issue? Is there another log I should be checking? Is there something obvious that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Is there a .crash file in /var/crash?

Comment: This is an old CPU, so I suppose you have run linux on it for a while. I also guess these problems you see are new to 20.04, which hints at a kernel problem. You can try the ubuntu mainline repository to see if the problem persists in the latest kernels ... thre are .deb files so they are easy to install.

Comment: @user535733, /var/crash is empty.

Comment: @TimRichardson, I'll try that tonight and see if this happens again. This is actually my first Linux install. Before that, this used to be a Windows box.